# My app crashes on launch?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I apologize for the broad title but I struggle to be more specific because iIhonestly don't know what went wrong. I was working on my app just like normal, and I hadn't tested for a couple of hours and also I think I updated something in android studio (It prompted me that some features were ready to be updated and I clicked)

Anyways, I've reverted everything I could think of that I might have screwed up, but it still won't work. I figure it might be something in the gradle files. Is anyone able to figure it out based on this?

```
--------- beginning of crash
10-24 14:10:47.679 2597-2597/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.jonet.lillehauaapp, PID: 2597
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.jonet.lillehauaapp-a1apOVe4GHJGjXWwg52Lag==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.jonet.lillehauaapp-a1apOVe4GHJGjXWwg52Lag==/lib/x86, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]] couldn't find "libnative-lib.so"
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1011)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1657)
at com.example.jonet.lillehauaapp.MainActivity.<clinit>(MainActivity.java:25)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do you use C++ in your project? Check that all is working as in docs: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html -
 - probably Android Studio update broke it (as usual)